# jQuery Ajax returns success although error is send by PHP (DOM Issue?)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I'm struggling around for a while now with a jQuery Ajax-Request. I'm building a Step-by-Step rating form. There is actually only one form which will be submitted on each step (the current step will is transmitted to PHP, only data that is important for that step will be validated).

**The Problem:**

The Ajax call is being submitted a lot of times without reloading the page. Although the ajax call (logged into Firebug console) is returning the right value (e.g. error if PHP validation fails) jQuery still picks up the old return values first (e.g. an old error or a success) and goes through the code again..

**Code**

Here is my jQuery function..

```
    $(ajax_cont).find(':submit').live('mouseup keyup',function(){

        submitButton  = $(this);

    });

    $(ajax_cont).live("submit", function(d) {

        var index = submitButton.attr("id").substring(9);

        d.preventDefault();

        var str = $(this).serialize() + "&step=" + index;
        var uri = ajax_default;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            asynch: false,
            url: uri,
            data: str,
            success: function(data) {

                $(".step_slider_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {

                    if(data.success) {

                        alert("jaa");

                        var next_step = "";

                        $(ajax_cont).parent().find(".error").html("").hide();
                        $(ajax_cont).find(".error_input").removeClass("error_input");

                        next_step = data.next;

                        console.log(data.next);

                        step_check = $(ajax_cont).find(".step_check").val();

                        if(step_check.indexOf(next_step) == -1) {

                            step_check = step_check + "," + next_step;

                        }

                        $(ajax_cont).find(".step_check").val(step_check);

                        var enabled_array = step_check.split(',');

                        $.each(enabled_array, function(enabled_index, enabled_value) {

                            if(enabled_array[enabled_index].length > 0) {

                                tmp_div = enabled_array[enabled_index];

                                $("body").find(".step_" + tmp_div).removeClass("disabled");

                            }

                        });

                        // Show - Hide Container

                        var id = "#step_" + next_step;

                        fadeDiv(id);

                        if(next_step == 3) {

                            preview_rating();
                            setHeight(ajax_cont.height());

                        }

                        // Navigation

                        $("body").find(".step").removeClass("step_active");
                        $("body").find(".step_" + next_step).addClass("step_active");

                    }

                    if(data.error) {

                        next_step = "";

                        $(ajax_cont).find(".error_input").removeClass("error_input");

                        error       =   data.error;
                        error_ids   =   data.error_id;

                        $.each(error_ids, function(index, value) {

                            id = "#" + error_ids[index];

                            $(id).addClass("error_input");

                        });

                        $(ajax_cont).parent().find(".error").html("<p>" + error + "</p>").show();

                        setHeight(ajax_cont.height());

                    }

                });

            },
            dataType: "json"

        });

        return false;

    });
```

I hope someone can find an answer to the problem.. Seems to make me crazy :(

Comment: wall of code!! where is the problem? point that.

Comment: Problem seems to be the Ajax request.. Still don't really get it. If I submit the form twice (first submit gives success -> next step) and I have an alert inserted in if(data.success) I get the alert shown although the PHP return value returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few problems with your code:

a) You are setting the ajaxSuccess event within the success event of an ajax call... 
b) You are using `data.success` to determine whether it is successful, which won't change because of an PHP error.

Instead, you should do:

```
$(ajax_cont).find(':submit').live('mouseup keyup',function(){

    submitButton  = $(this);

});

$(ajax_cont).live("submit", function(d) {

    var index = submitButton.attr("id").substring(9);

    d.preventDefault();

    var str = $(this).serialize() + "&step=" + index;
    var uri = ajax_default;

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        asynch: false,
        url: uri,
        data: str,
        success: function(data) {

            if(data.success) {

                alert("jaa");

                var next_step = "";

                $(ajax_cont).parent().find(".error").html("").hide();
                $(ajax_cont).find(".error_input").removeClass("error_input");

                next_step = data.next;

                console.log(data.next);

                step_check = $(ajax_cont).find(".step_check").val();

                if(step_check.indexOf(next_step) == -1) {

                    step_check = step_check + "," + next_step;

                }

                $(ajax_cont).find(".step_check").val(step_check);

                var enabled_array = step_check.split(',');

                $.each(enabled_array, function(enabled_index, enabled_value) {

                    if(enabled_array[enabled_index].length > 0) {

                        tmp_div = enabled_array[enabled_index];

                        $("body").find(".step_" + tmp_div).removeClass("disabled");

                    }

                });

                // Show - Hide Container

                var id = "#step_" + next_step;

                fadeDiv(id);

                if(next_step == 3) {

                    preview_rating();
                    setHeight(ajax_cont.height());

                }

                // Navigation

                $("body").find(".step").removeClass("step_active");
                $("body").find(".step_" + next_step).addClass("step_active");

            }

            if(data.error) {

                next_step = "";

                $(ajax_cont).find(".error_input").removeClass("error_input");

                error       =   data.error;
                error_ids   =   data.error_id;

                $.each(error_ids, function(index, value) {

                    id = "#" + error_ids[index];

                    $(id).addClass("error_input");

                });

                $(ajax_cont).parent().find(".error").html("<p>" + error + "</p>").show();

                setHeight(ajax_cont.height());

            }

        },
        error : function()
        {
            alert('there was an error parsing the json, or processing your request');
        },
        dataType: "json"

    });

    return false;

});
```

Note, I have removed the `ajaxSuccess` event and implemented an `error` event to your ajax request.

Comment: Lifesaver :) You made my day ;) Didn't thought it to be such a trivial problem!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @thecodeparadox - wall of code. Too much code is just as bad as too little code :-)

Going purely by what you have said it sounds like you have multiple AJAX submits and you are using the response from an older request. Try using something like Ajax Manager http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/ which lets you queue and cancel requests.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. There is only one request send to PHP at a time (as shown by Firebug). But still it looks like old return values still survive a new request..